# Group data by week but display date format axis

Tags: excel, date, charts

I have data which I want to display on an Excel column chart. It represents the number of sales per week, where the date is the first day of the week:

[image]

If I leave the dates as dates then Excel interprets this as data for one day out of seven, so I get thin columns with large gaps:

[image]

I can resolve this by formatting the dates as text, which gives me the style I want:

[image]

However, I want a date scale where only the first of each month is labelled, which I think requires a date formatted axis.

Basically, I want to achieve this in Excel instead of paint:

[image]

Any ideas on how (if) this can be done?

Comment: It's not a specfic programming question, but I'll accept a VBA solution if there is one.

Comment: I could also use the answer. If you receive it here or on Superuser, please, let me know.

Comment: See answer below....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is make a line chart on the date axis, add and format error bars, then hide the lines and markers. Use the Minus option for the error bars, with no End Caps, and a Percentage Value of 100%, so the error bar reaches the horizontal axis. Format the error bar lines to simulate a thicker bar.

[image: Error Bars as Column Chart]

Comment: That's an interesting approach - it hadn't occurred to me to use error bars. I like this solution because it doesn't use any "dummy" data. The solution I ended up using involved a series along the x axis with data labels as axis labels and got very complicated due to having secondary axes all over the place. But this is better!

Comment: Just another tip for anyone using this - you also need to set the error bars to Direction: Minus or it appears as double the line value

Comment: @TomC - It does say to "Use the Minus option for the error bars". :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this recently and the way I got around it was to create a second set of values using the =Text(A1,"MMM YY") formula.

Instructions on your actual sample data:

Insert a column between Week beginning and Sales (For the purpose of this we will assume Week beginning is in column A)

In the new column B row 2 enter this formula:

```
=IF(TEXT(A2,"MMM YY")<>TEXT(A1,"MMM YY"),TEXT(A2,"MMM YY"),"")
```

Here we are telling it only to list if it is the first instance of the new month

Copy it down as far as column A has data

Highlight the data in column B and C

Create a column chart

Your chart will now look how you wanted it

Edit: I just noticed you have "Week beginning" but I assume you want your chart to be week ending for the titles?

If so then make the B2 formula

```
=TEXT(A2+5,"MMM YY")
```

and then make the B3 one

```
=IF(TEXT(A3+4,"MMM YY")<>TEXT(A2+4,"MMM YY"),TEXT(A3+4,"MMM YY"),"")
```

And drag down, I have added 4 on the assumption your week closes on Friday (Monday + 4 Days) but you can adjust that accordingly

Comment: This is only an approximate work around - it doesn't actually mark the beginning of the month where the month starts (i.e. potentially mid-week).